# Word/phrase for taking the pilot out of the equation in turning a piloted aircraft into a UAV

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a word/phrase for the process of taking the pilot out of the equation in turning an existing piloted aircraft into a UAV?  How would you describe it?  I am thinking of something that begins with "de-" but can't complete it.

Comment: Since the U in UAV is *unmanned,* would *unmanning* or *demanning* work?

Comment: @AndrewLeach — given the existing meaning of [unmanning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unman) I wouldn't suggest that word for aircraft except if you want to make it very very clear they will not be used for traditionally “male” purposes. Well, since UAVs (drones) are never used for warfare, that would be fitting... oh wait :|

Comment: Computerising? or Mechanicising?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one takes the human out of any process, it is considered *automated*.

After comments:
I'd like to use depiloted for this purpose, as it would be a reasonable explanation.

However, I think the question is more likely to be answered as *converted to drone*.

> Once the aircraft has been converted to a drone, it can fly autonomously or be remotely piloted.

Comment: The sentence is the definition and usage in the context of the question.

Comment: +1 Good point.  An automated system can still be supervised though, and that's what poses the problem in this case.

Comment: I regret that I don't understand the problem regarding supervision. *Completely automated*? *Autonomous*? But these wouldn't describe the automating process, but rather a state after the process completes. Are you looking to describe the process or the state after the process is complete?

Comment: Again, thanks for your clarifying comments.  I am after the state following the process.  Take a currently piloted aircraft, say an F-16.  After the process, the same aircraft becomes a UAV, controlled either from the ground or autonomously.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Not only the answer itself, but the process you see taking place to reach that answer, as in this case, is a pleasure to experience.

Comment: An "automated" process or machine may or may not have human supervision. In practice, I think outside of science fiction any machine has SOME level of human supervision, some person who programs it or sets its controls in some way. If there is very little human control, people call it "a fully autonomous automated process", as opposed to a "semi-autonomous automated process". If it was "non-autonomous" I think that would mean it isn't automated at all, so it's not a very meaningful term.